# Detect two hardware button press simultaneously

Tags: android

I want to add listener when my two hardware button presses like volume button and power button. But i came to know that you can't override power button. Actually i want to take snaps of screen so i came up with this solution. So this is what i wanted to achieve if you have any suggestion about this please share it.

Comment: Power Button? Impossible. But possible via a custom firmware. Try another Key combination, key sequence, touch sequence or a simple button.

Answer (score 3):

In your Activity. Try below code for Volume UP + Power key. You can reduce PRESS_INTERVAL to get effect like both buttons are pressed at the same time. Hope This Helps!

```
private static final int PRESS_INTERVAL = 700;
private long mUpKeyEventTime = 0;
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER == event.getKeyCode()) {            
            if ((event.getEventTime() - mUpKeyEventTime) < PRESS_INTERVAL) {
                // This is to check if Volume UP key and Power key are pressed at the same time.
                // Do the Task. Here You can add logic to take screenshot
            }
            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP == keyCode){
            mUpKeyEventTime = event.getEventTime();
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need override [onKeyDown](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html#onKeyDown(int,%20android.view.KeyEvent)) and [onKeyUp](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html#onKeyUp(int,%20android.view.KeyEvent)) events to detect two buttons pressed.

```
 public boolean first,second;

 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER){
        first = true;
    }
    else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
        second = true;
    }

    if(first && second) {
        // Two buttons pressed, Do your stuff
    }
    return true;
 }

 public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER){
        first = false;
    }
    else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
        second = false;
    }
    return true;
 }
```

Comment: But how can i do with power button and volume button. Because pressing volume button up and down at the same time... you know not seems so logical

Comment: @user2934930 recheck my answer.