# android - Detect two hardware button long press at the same time

Tags: android

My android application need send an duress request to server when user long press Volume up and power button at the same time (Similar take a screenshot  when press Volume down and power button at the same time). I have read about `onKeyLongPress` method:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) 
    {
        Log.w("eventKey", "Hello");
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

but this method only use when user long press an hardware button. So my question is How to detect **TWO** hardware button long press at the same time in  Android? Thank for any suggest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect two hardware button press simultaneously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420414/detect-two-hardware-button-press-simultaneously)

Comment: @Michael i have read that question before. In my case, two button are pressed at the same time.

Comment: Even if they're pressed at the same time I would expect you to get one onKeyDown event per button.